# Export websphere profile

Tags: websphere

I am trying to export a websphere profile. Tried various commands under wsadmin

```
$AdminTask exportWasprofile {-archive c:/myCell.car}
AdminTask.exportWasprofile('[-archive c:/myCell.car]')
AdminTask.exportWasprofile(['-archive', 'c:/myCell.car'])
```

all return  a syntax error
com.ibm.bsf.BSFException: error while eval'ing Jacl expression:

how do you export a profile?
(Websphere 8.5.5.14)

Comment: Make sure you start `wsadmin` with correct language support - either `-lang jython` or `-lang jacl`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first example you give is correct for use with wsadmin in jacl language mode, the third is correct for jython lang mode.  The error message you posted indicates that wsadmin is operating in jacl language mode.

Answer (score 0):

You're almost right, this one should work.

`AdminTask.exportWasprofile(['-archive c:\myCell.car'])`